# How to get the first and last values in jquery with a specific style?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="itemContainer">
<li data-number="1" style="display: none;"></li>
<li data-number="2" style="display: none;"></li>
<li data-number="3" style="display: list-item;"></li>
<li data-number="4" style="display: list-item;"></li>
<li data-number="5" style="display: list-item;"></li>
</ul>
```

i want to get the value of data-number of first and last elements of li with display: list-item so with this example i should get 3 and 5

```
if ($("#itemContainer>li").css('display') == 'list-item'){
    var first = parseInt($("#itemContainer>li").first().data("number"), 10);
    var last = parseInt($("#itemContainer>li").last().data("number"), 10);
    $("#itemContainer>li").hide().slice(first, last).show(); 
}
```

im always getting 1 and 5?

Comment: Your slice isn't going to select the items you want, since the numbers start at `1`, but `slice` counts from `0`.

Comment: Why are you using `data-number` instead of `.index()`? Do you need the numbers to be different from the zero-based indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.filter()` to get all the `li` with `display: list-item`, then use `.first()` and `.last()` to select the appropriate elements from this subset.

```js
var lis = $("#itemContainer>li").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('display') == 'list-item';
});
var first = lis.first().data("number");
var last = lis.last().data("number");
$("#itemContainer>li").hide().slice(first, last).show();
$("#first").text(first);
$("#last").text(last);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="itemContainer">
  <li data-number="1" style="display: none;">1</li>
  <li data-number="2" style="display: none;">2</li>
  <li data-number="3" style="display: list-item;">3</li>
  <li data-number="4" style="display: list-item;">4</li>
  <li data-number="5" style="display: list-item;">5</li>
</ul>
First = <span id="first"></span><br>
Last = <span id="last"></span>
```

BTW, you don't need to use `parseInt`, because `.data()` parses the data value as JSON.

Comment: there is an excess closing paranthesis on the `return` last part `'list-item')`
you can also add a -1 to the slice index to start it on list item 3, because of the zero-base index of slice start

Comment: I'm not even sure why he's using `data-number` for this, he could just use `.index()`.

Comment: @Baramar yes i would like to use index, can you show me how?

Comment: Use `.index()` instead of `.data("number")`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#itemContainer li").each(function() {//iterate through each li
    
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'list-item') {//check the display
    var first = parseInt($("#itemContainer li").first().data("number"), 10);
    var last = parseInt($("#itemContainer li").last().data("number"), 10);
      
      console.log(first+ " " + last)//log first and last
    $("#itemContainer li").hide().slice(first, last).show();
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="itemContainer">
  <li data-number="1" style="display: none;"></li>
  <li data-number="2" style="display: none;"></li>
  <li data-number="3" style="display: list-item;"></li>
  <li data-number="4" style="display: list-item;"></li>
  <li data-number="5" style="display: list-item;"></li>
</ul>
```

Do this

Comment: thanks, how do i count also the list-item in the dom?

Comment: the code to check whether it's display is list-item is correct, but it will still select the li with `display:none` since you are still trying to call an unfiltered list item `$("#itemContainer li")`